# One month limit - Reporting Service

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am building a report in Micrososft SQL Reporting Services and, I have two date fields, startDate and endDate.

I need to limit the date range, at least in thirty days (or a month). For example, if startDate is 2012/01/01 and endDate is 2012/02/02, it should raise an error message, otherwise (being less than thirty days of difference), it can continue. How can I do that in reporting service?

Comment: Have you thought about using drop down list with dynamic values (E.G., 1 - 5 days, 6 - 10 days ... etc)?

Comment: You could write a VB program to call the report which checks the parameters first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a data set to provide default values for your endDate parameter based on your startDate parameter.

Add a Dataset named DefaultStartDate.  Set query text to:

```
select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) as [startDate];
```

Add a Parameter named startDate.  Set type to Date/Time and get the default value from the DefaultStartDate query:

[image: Default Values / Dataset=DefaultStartDate / Value=startDate]

Add a Dataset named ValidEndDates.  Set query text to something like the following, to generate a list of valid end dates based on the start date:

```
with A as
( select 1 as i UNION ALL select i+1 from A where i<30 )
select DATEADD(dd, i, @startDate) as [endDate] from A;
```

Add a Parameter named endDate.  Set type to Date/Time and get the available values from the ValidEndDates Dataset:

[image: Available Values / DataSet=ValidEndDates / Value=endDate / Label=endDate]

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but there is an answer. A high-level explanation of the solution is to write code in the Report Properties, add a hidden parameter that contains code to validate the parameters, and a conditional expression in the DataSet. Please see the following link for a detailed explanation: [https://gugiaji.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/easy-step-by-step-ssrs-parameter-validation-using-code](https://gugiaji.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/easy-step-by-step-ssrs-parameter-validation-using-code/)