# How to limit ssrs report for a month without creating expression dataset

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created an SSRS report which uses many subqueries and joins and it uses 2 parameters StartDate and EndDate.
I want to limit my report to 1 Month i.e User can select any StartDate but their end date should be less than or equal 31 days from that. If they select end date >31 then it should show the error message.
It'll be helpful if the limit uses a month instead of 31 days as feb consists only 28/29 days and some months has 30 days only.

Note: I saw many solutions referring to create a new dataset with expression in it. Since my Query is too long I don't want to create a new dataset.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One month limit - Reporting Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294570/one-month-limit-reporting-service)

Comment: If they choose something like 3/13/2016 they should only be allowed to query until 3/1 or 2/13?

Comment: If you don't like Hannover Fist's code, check the SQL by Tarzan in the identified duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to limit the dates that the user is select, I would create a dataset of the possible days and let the user select from them for the second parameter.

```
DECLARE @END_DATE  DATE  = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @START_DATE)

;WITH GETDATES AS  
    (  
        SELECT @START_DATE AS THEDATE
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1, THEDATE) FROM GETDATES  
        WHERE THEDATE < @END_DATE  
)

SELECT * FROM GETDATES 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Declaration variables is not allowed in SSRS :(
Is there any way to use parameters that are created earlier

Comment: @NaveenBodapati - not sure what you mean - I DECLARE in Datasets. Are you getting the `The Declare SQL construct or statement is not supported` when you click on the **Query Designer**? You'll have to click on the **Edit as Text** to get the query in the (half-assed) editor. I did need to change the select to `SELECT CAST(@START_DATE AS DATE) AS THEDATE` to get it to work there.

Comment: @NaveenBodapati  can you reply to the comment in the post?

Comment: still same,it is not accepting variable declaration, getting error ORA-06550 and PLS-00103

Comment: Ah - you're connecting to an **Oracle** Server. One of the many differences is that parameters use a colon instead of the @ symbol - `:parametername`. There are others but it's been years since I've worked with an Oracle server.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember all the differences between SQL Server and Oracle SQL. You should try working out the query with an Oracle SQL editor first before migrating it to the SSRS dataset. Or could you use a different **SQL Server** source for this **date** dataset?